# Define which entity manager is associated with JpaRepository

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am writing a Spring Boot application which has multiple dataSources and entityManagers and I want to use the JPA CrudRepository interface like:

`@Repository
 public interface Car extends CrudRepository<Car.class, Long> {}`.

I get the following error:

> Error creating bean with name 'carRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#350d0774' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#350d0774': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource

I have not been able to figure out how to tell the JpaRepositoryFactory which entity manager to use when building the repositories.  It defaults to trying to inject an EntityManagerFactory called: entityManagerFactory

Comment: What does your `applicationContext.xml` or Java Configuration look like; have you created an EntityManagerFactory Bean in the configuration? [Here is the documentation.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm-jpa)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_custom_namespace_attributes) on attributes.

Use the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation below on your Java configuration class
with `entityManagerFactoryRef` and `transactionManagerRef` attributes.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
        "com.myapp.repositories" }, entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryRef1", transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerRef1")
```

Remove `@Repository` annotation on `Car` interface. Spring will register it as JPA repository if you specify `basePackages` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

what you can do in your spring.xml

```
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.a.b.repository"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="yrEntityMAnagerFectorybeanRef"
    transaction-manager-ref="yourTransactionManagerBeanRef"/>
```

in your EntityManagerFactory bean you will refer your entitymanager bean.